# How to create folder automatically before files upload via multer so that those files get stored in that created folder in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, multer, create-directory

This is my multer code to upload multiple files.

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './public/files/'+ req.user.id)
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    x = file.originalname; //+path.extname(file.originalname);
  cb(null,x);
  }
});

var upload = multer({storage: storage});
```

This is the post request where files get submitted on click submit.

```
router.post(upload.array("FileUpload",12), function(req, res, next) {

//Here accessing the body datas.

})
```

So what I want is that, I want to create a `folder` first with the name of the `ID` generated which can be access from the `req.body` and then upload those files into that folder respectively.
But since I cannot access the `body` first before upload I am unable to create that respective `folder directory.` Is there any other way around which I can think of and implement this?

Updated Solution using fs-extra package.

```
const multer = require('multer');
let fs = require('fs-extra');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    let Id = req.body.id;
    fs.mkdirsSync('./public/files/'+ req.user.id + '/' + Id);
    cb(null, './public/files/'+ req.user.id + '/' + Id)
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    x = file.originalname; //+path.extname(file.originalname);
  cb(null,x);
  }
});

var upload = multer({storage: storage});
```

This is the post request where files get submitted on click submit.

```
router.post(upload.array("FileUpload",12), function(req, res, next) {

//Here accessing the body datas.

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to install first the `fs-extra` which will create folder

create seprate folder for multer like `multerHelper.js`

```
const multer = require('multer');
let fs = require('fs-extra');

let storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    let Id = req.body.id;
    let path = `tmp/daily_gasoline_report/${Id}`;
    fs.mkdirsSync(path);
    cb(null, path);
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    // console.log(file);

    let extArray = file.mimetype.split("/");
    let extension = extArray[extArray.length - 1];
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + "." + extension);
 }
})

let upload = multer({ storage: storage });

let createUserImage = upload.array('images', 100);

let multerHelper = {
    createUserImage,
}

module.exports = multerHelper;
```

in your routes import multerhelper file

```
const multerHelper = require("../helpers/multer_helper");

router.post(multerHelper , function(req, res, next) {

//Here accessing the body datas.

})
```

Comment: Where to find helpers/multer_helper?

Comment: you have to create it in your project folder

Comment: I have updated the solution according to your answer. Is it correct? Please check after "Updated Solution using fs-extra package" added in my question.

Comment: I have created sepreate folder for routes also so this method worked for me

Comment: Didn't test yet. Will do it and let you know if it works. And then I will upvote your answer as well for sure thanks! :)